# Remove appData after uninstall Electron app

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder, appdata

I want to remove the appData after my app was uninstalled.
The `deleteAppDataOnUninstall: true` option was useful when i run the `uninstaller.exe`,but not work when i install the app again.
**When I want to install a version v2 to cover the version v1 existed in computer,i want to remove appData and create a new one.**
I use the `include: installer.nsh` to do this.

```
!macro customInstall
  RMDir /r "$APPDATA\${APP_PACKAGE_NAME}"
!macroend
```

But the question is:
`$APPDATA`variable in `nsis` is `C:\ProgramData`,the appData path I got in `Electron app.getPath('userData')` is `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming`

**What should I do to remove the appData folder got from `app.getPath('userData')`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$AppData depends on the `SetShellVarContext` setting. In your case it has been set to `all` and this means you are doing a all users install and you should not really modify a users profile.

If you want to ignore this advice then make sure you have v3.08 and use $USERAPPDATA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,this is helpful for me! But I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote...

Comment: In my app,`$installMode` is set to `all`,but  I can't find where to set this option in `electron-builder`,maybe this is a sideeffect by another option?  Even the `$installMode` is `all`,`app.getPath('appData')` still returns `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming`,maybe this is the real question.

Comment: Now I can set `SetShellVarContext current ` to  get user appData path,but what will happen if I don't restore this variable in the end?

Comment: The default context is probably set by oneClick and perMachine electron settings.